# OAuth2RestTemplate doesnt refresh the token after it expired

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I am using Spring OAuth2RestTemplate and the token is not refreshed after its expired. Below is my token provider. What am I missing? Any pointers would really help.

```
@Bean
        public AccessTokenProvider clientAccessTokenProvider() {
            ClientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider accessTokenProvider = new ClientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider();
            accessTokenProvider.setRequestFactory(getClientHttpRequestFactory());
            return accessTokenProvider;
        }
```

Comment: I followed this repo for setting the config: https://github.com/mariubog/oauth-client-sample/blob/master/src/main/java/oauth/client/demo/config/OauthClientConfig.java

Comment: It can happen if the token response(especially the expires_in) is not in the default format. Did you verify that ?

Comment: Which version of Spring Boot are you working with?

Comment: org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2 is the OAuthClient and sprinboot version: 2.1.8.RELEASE

Comment: @Abbin It is in the default format milliseconds

Comment: Do you guys have a example code in github, that I could follow?

Comment: You could give Spring Boot 2.2 a try if you are able, there have been several changes to the OAUTH2 implementation in that version and a google seems to indicate that token refreshing may work more out of the box when upgrading to that version.

Comment: Its uses webFlux I am not using webFlux in my project yet. And its more for reactive programing

Comment: I use client-credentials, which doesnt support refresh token, I looked into the spring code and found it

Answer (score 0):

ClientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider doesn't not support "Refresh Token" according to spring boot oAuth implementation.

I fixed the problem by checking the expiry and setting the token in oAuthContext to null before making the rest call.

```
  private void checkTokenExpiry() {
        OAuth2ClientContext oAuth2ClientContext = oAuth2RestOperations.getOAuth2ClientContext();
        if (oAuth2ClientContext == null) {
            return;
        }
        OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = oAuth2ClientContext.getAccessToken();
        if (accessToken != null && (accessToken.getExpiresIn() > 5000 || accessToken
            .isExpired())) { //5 seconds
            log.info("Token expired");
            oAuth2RestOperations.getOAuth2ClientContext()
                .setAccessToken(null); //to re-fetch the token
        }
    }
```